# How do I set the value of a NumberField in EXTjs?

Tags: extjs4

I have a `NumberField` in `ExtJS4` that is on a panel.

After I load some data (`via an AJAX JSONStore`), I want to populate some number fields but can't seem to get it or find documentation.

Any clues on where to look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
numberfield.setValue(yourvalue);
```

Comment: Yes, I actually did that.  However, I had the number field as an item in a panel.  So I had to actually create a new number field and insert it that way (created it OUTSIDE the panel).  Once I did that, the setValue worked.  Thanks